# Como saber se um ponto (x, y) está dentro da porcentágem preenchida de um gráfico tipo pizza?

Tags: python, matemática, gráfico

Eu cheguei a este código que mostra se um ponto (x, y) está dentro ou fora de um circulo em um plano cartesiano.

```
def dentro_fora(p, x = 0, y = 0):

    r = cx = cy = 50

    if (x - cx)**2 + (y - cy)**2 < r**2:
        return 'dentro'
    else:
        return 'fora'
```

Mas eu precisava saber se este ponto está na parte preenchida do circulo, por exemplo, se eu tenho uns 33% do circulo preenchidos (supondo que seja um gráfico tipo pizza) como descubro se o ponto (12, 55) está dentro da área preenchida?

Considerando que o centro do circulo é o ponto (50, 50) e o raio é 50.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você está usando uma fórmula básica de distância, que na prática simplesmente te diz se o ponto está no círculo ou não.

Como ela já basta para determinar se está no gráfico, só falta saber o ângulo do ponto em relação ao centro. É deste ângulo que vai extrair a porcentagem onde o ponto se encontra.

Tem uma função matemática que te dá isso pronto, é o arco-tangente com 2 parâmetros:

```
 angulo = math.atan2( x, y )
```

sendo que `x, y` são as coordenadas do ponto em relação ao **centro** do círculo, no caso do gráfico da sua pergunta, seria `( x - 50, y - 50 )`.

Importante considerar que o `atan2` considera o ponto mais à direita como início, e normalmente os gráficos circulares usam a origem no topo, sendo assim, pode fazer uma jogada com a simetria:

```
 angulo = math.atan2( -y, -x )
```

E com o ajuste do centro:

```
 angulo = math.atan2( -(y - 50), -(x - 50) )
```

(ajuste conforme necessário, o segredo é inverter as coordenadas e por o negativo em algum ou ambos os lados, dependendo da origem usada)

Para saber em porcentagem, em relação ao gráfico de pizza/torta basta dividir o ângulo por 2 PI (que representa os 360º em Radianos), e multiplicar por 100:

```
porcentagem = angulo / ( math.pi * 2 ) * 100
```

(não simplifiquei a fórmula para facilitar a leitura)

Claro que se você tiver várias "fatias" na pizza, vai ter que somar a porcentagem de cada uma delas até passar da "porcentagem" obtida na fórmula acima.

Exemplo: se o ponto está no 62%, e voce tem pedaços de 20%, 30% e 40%:

```
  Pedaço 1 - 20%  (20 >= 62, falso, vamos pro próximo )
  Pedaço 2 - 30%  (30 + 20 >= 62, falso, vamos pro próximo )
  Pedaço 3 - 40%  (40 + 30 + 20 >= 62, verdadeiro, achamos nosso pedaço )
```

Provavelmente é o caso de implementar com um `loop` bem simples.

Comment: Eu entendi mas não entendi... veja bem, eu sei qual é a porcentágem, só quero saber se um determinado ponto x, y está dentro dessa porcentágem no circulo, eu editei a pergunta e coloquei uma imagem, da uma olhada!

Comment: No caso, eu poderia querer saber se um ponto (50, 20) por exemplo, estaria na área preta ou na brabca! Ou fora do circulo

Comment: A acho que entendi agora, se eu tenho o circulo com 33% preenchido, e eu quero saber se o ponto (55, 50) está dentro desta área, com a formula que vc passou eu chego a 13,2... então 13,2 é menor que 33 portanto está dentro da área, certo?

Comment: Ah, obrigado, eu realmente não sou bom com matemática, valeu!

Comment: @PattersonSilva acrescentei uma breve descrição de como fazer para saber de vários "gomos" em qual está. Basta um loop somando as porcentagens. Quando for igual ou maior que "porcentagem" é a fatia certa.

Comment: @PattersonSilva talvez, dependendo do seu gráfico, tenha que ajustar os sinais de x e y no atan, mas aí só você comentar as coordenadas e os valores obtidos que a gente ajusta.

Comment: Grande resposta! :) Bastante didática. Merecia mais do que +1. :)